# Generic stream to output both to a file or cout -- C++

Tags: c++, stream

I would like to change a function that displays some info about the class so that
can print to the screen or write to a file depending on the kind of stream I am passing to the function.

I would like to have a function like:

```
void output(int x, default (what class do I need here??) &stream=cout){
    stream << x ;
}
```

What is the proper way to do that???
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a question I asked that is quite possibly a duplicate, at least in terms of passing an `ostream` to a function with the ability to choose which you like when calling the function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356300/is-it-possible-to-pass-cout-or-fout-to-a-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally want `std::ostream&`. Note that most programmers would just overload `operator<<` rather than define a separate `output()` function like you've done.

Comment: Thanks for the help chrisaycock. I define an output function because it takes in input other variables that I need to write certain things to disk :) I just kept the example minimal!

Comment: I'm sorry, but it dosn't work if I write: void output(default std::ostream& os=std::cout) I get some syntax error message. How would yout write that?

Comment: Some generic syntax error.. I rewrote the function from scratch and it worked though.. must have been some silly typo...

Comment: I don't think the keyword ``default`` in ``void output(default std::ostream& os=std::cout)`` is valid.  To overload a function by providing a default value for an argument, just add `` = value``, no ``default`` is needed.