# Passing std::ostream to function?

Tags: c++

I'm working through the example programs of *Wiley's Teach Yourself C++* (7th Edition) using LLVM clang++ (version 3.1 on FreeBSD) as my compiler. In Ch. 23, "Class Inheritance", the following code is provided:

Date.h - the base class:

```
...snip..
inline void Date::Display(std::ostream& os)
   { os << "Date: " << *this; }
...snip...
```

SpecialDate.h - the class derived from Date and overloads the Display() function:

```
#include "Date.h"
...snip...
void Display(std::ostream& os)
   { os << "SpecialDate: " << *this; }
...snip...
```

23-1.cpp - instantiates an object of SpecialDate and uses it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SpecialDate.h"
int main()
{
...snip... 
// da, mo, & yr are all ints and declared
SpecialDate dt(da, mo, yr);
...snip...
dt.Display();
...snip...
```

When I compile the code, the only error I get is:

```
./23-1.cpp:14:14: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0
            dt.Display();
            ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
./SpecialDate.h:15:2: note: 'Display' declared here
    void Display(std::ostream& os)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I can see that I need to pass by reference a std::ostream type variable to Display(), but I'm stumped on how to proceed.  FWIW: both Date.h and SpecialDate.h overload the `<<` operator. I've tried:

```
dt.Display(std::cout); /* all sorts of weird compiler errors */
...
std::ostream os; /* error: calling a protected constructor of class */
dt.Display(os);
...
std::cout << dt.Display(); /* same "too few arguments" error */
```

What do I need to do to get this code to compile?

EDIT:
Chris, clang++ errors for `dt.Display(std::cout);`:

```
/tmp/23-1-IecGtZ.o: In function `SpecialDate::Display(std::ostream&)':
./23-1.cpp:(.text._ZN11SpecialDate7DisplayERSo[_ZN11SpecialDate7DisplayERSo]+0x34):    undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, SpecialDate&)'
/tmp/23-1-IecGtZ.o: In function `Date::Date(int, int, int)':
./23-1.cpp:(.text._ZN4DateC2Eiii[_ZN4DateC2Eiii]+0x34): undefined reference to `Date::SetDate(int, int, int)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Also, `#include <iostream>` is in both Date.h and SpecialDate.h.

EDIT 2: After re-reading the errors for `dt.Display(std::cout);`, I realized that the compiler was not seeing the source for SpecialDate and Date, just the headers. So I added those to the command line and it finally compiled without errors!

```
clang++ 23-1.cpp Date.cpp SpecialDate.cpp
```

Unfortunately, the behavior is not as expected (the date is not being displayed), but my original question has been answered. I'll continue to poke at it. Thanks for your patience with a noob!

Comment: `dt.Display(std::cout);` should work. We'll need something like an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and/or the compiler errors to see why it isn't.

Comment: Make sure you have `<iostream>` included where you have `Display` in the headers as well.

Comment: You're missing the code for `SpecialDate`'s `<<` operator and the `Date::SetData(int, int, int)` function. Your either not linking with them, forgot to implement them, or have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, @molbdnilo. I came to the same realization and was editing my post when you commented.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356300/is-it-possible-to-pass-cout-or-fout-to-a-function