# Is it possible to show void function cout output in a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, function, void, cout

Is it possible to show cout output on a file instead of showing it in the console/terminal?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void showhello()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    ofstream fw;
    fw.open("text.txt");
    fw << showhello() << endl;
}
```

If I simply put the cout << "Hello World" << endl; in the main, it will of course show "Hello World" in the terminal.
Now instead of showing it in the terminal, I want to make it show in the text.txt file.

**Restriction:**
Let's say the function showhello() contains a thousand of cout output, so you cannot use something like:

```
fw << "Hello World" << endl;
```

or a copy paste in a string. It must be fw << function.

Comment: What you are doing should work fine as far as I can understand what you want.

Comment: [`How to redirect cin & cout to a file`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Comment: Chances are you'll be better off refactoring `showHello` to take an `ostream` as an argument and output to that. You'll have the option of providing an overload of `showHello` that takes no arguments calls the refactored version passing in `std::cout`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass cout or fout to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356300/is-it-possible-to-pass-cout-or-fout-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do re-direction like following :

```
std::streambuf *oldbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //save 
std::cout.rdbuf(fw.rdbuf()); 

showhello(); // Contents to cout will be written to text.txt

//reset back to standard input
std::cout.rdbuf(oldbuf);
```

Comment: It really works. I'm a little surprised to see you simply need to put the function between the streambuf and cout.rdbuf.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a reference to stream as argument:

```
std::ostream& showhello(std::ostream& stream) {
    return stream << "Hello World";
}
```

//Usage (I was surpised that it works, thanks @T.C.):

```
ofstream fw;
fw.open("text.txt");
std::cout << showhello << '\n';
```

//Alternatively:

```
showhello(fw) << '\n';
```

I'm using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`,
because `std::endl` forces flushing the stream.
When you write to console, the difference may be almost unnoticeable,
but when you write to disk,
it forces to get access to disk **right now**,
instead of waiting until there is enoungh data
to make saving to disk efficent.

Comment: The cool thing about this is that if you do this you can actually write `fw << showhello << '\n'`.