# Pass a Stringstream into a method

Tags: c++, stringstream

What I want to do is create a method that takes a stringstream as a parameter, write to it in the method, then read from the stringstream outside of the method.

For example something like this.

```
void writeToStream(std::stringstream sstr){
   sstr << "Hello World";
}

int main(){
   std::stringstream sstr;
   writeToStream(sstr);
   std::cout << sstr.str();
}
```

I am getting compile time errors though when I do this. It might be because I am supposed to be using a reference to the stringstream or something like that. I have tried different combinations of using references or pointers but nothing seems to work?

Comment: What "compile time errors"? When you receive an error message, please post it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356300/is-it-possible-to-pass-cout-or-fout-to-a-function

Comment: Also, what "combination of references or pointers" did you use?  As you can see from the answers given, the code works correctly when using a reference parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::stringstream` cannot be copied how you have it written for your function. This is because of reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed). You can, however, pass the `std::stringstream` as a reference to your function, which is totally legal. Here is some example code:

```
#include <sstream>

void writeToStream(std::stringstream &sstr){
   sstr << "Hello World";
}

int main(){
   std::stringstream sstr;
   writeToStream(sstr);
   std::cout << sstr.str();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't *copy* a stream, therefore you can't pass it by value.

Pass it by reference instead:

```
void writeToStream(std::stringstream &sstr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your function as follows and include `<sstream>`

```
void writeToStream(std::stringstream& sstr){
       sstr << "Hello World";
    }
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34b86cfbd3cf87fc